# How to fill TStringGrid in Delphi FireMonkey?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to create a multi-device application in Delphi. I have placed my TStringGrid on form. Increased column count to 4. I have a stringlist List3 with 4 elements. List3 does contain data.

```
StringGrid1.Cells[0,0] := 'adc';
StringGrid1.cells[1,0] := 'efg';
StringGrid1.Cells[2,0] := 'hij';

for n1 := 1 to p2-1 do
begin
    StringGrid1.Cells[3,n1] := Trim(List3[0]);
    StringGrid1.cells[0,n1] := Trim(List3[1]);
    StringGrid1.Cells[1,n1] := Trim(List3[2]);
    StringGrid1.Cells[2,n1] := Trim(List3[3]);
end
```

No data shows up in StringGrid1. neither hard coded for row 0 or dynamically using for loop.

Comment: In view of the `Android` tag, is  the form is an FMX one rather than a VCL one?

Comment: What is p2? What is StringGrid1.RowCount ?

Comment: I am new to Delphi 10.2. The form is what Delphi presented when I said I wanted to create my first multi-device application. I believe it to be FMX. P2 is a derived integer from code - not present - value is 64. Info for P2 received from php page. StringGrid1.RowCount is set to p2.

Comment: @MartynA Well, it does say "multi-device", which is what Delphi labels an FMX application.

Answer (score 1):

The Tstringgrid was not filling because I was in usb debug mode. Once I disconnected from computer and executed the apk the grid filled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to refresh or clicking some visual components in your form?

FMX needed some action to reload your data. The easiest way to determine this, just try to use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate functions in it.

```
StringGrid1.BeginUpdate; 

for n1 := 1 to p2-1 do
begin
 StringGrid1.Cells[3,n1] := Trim(List3[0]);
 StringGrid1.cells[0,n1] := Trim(List3[1]);
 StringGrid1.Cells[1,n1] := Trim(List3[2]);
 StringGrid1.Cells[2,n1] := Trim(List3[3]);
end;

StringGrid1.EndUpdate;
```